# Executing a php Script within another PHP script

Tags: php, shell

I have a PHP file that is being run on the internet. In that file, I want to execute another PHP file that is stored on my computer in the same directory as the main file. I am using this to execute the PHP file.

```
exec('php trial.php', $output);
```

This produces no output, the file `trial.php` runs two executes a program and pipes the input to a text file.

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

use this line :

```
$result = shell_exec('php trial.php');
```

or use this :

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://localhost/trial.php");
```